# Can I create data interaction between Server and Client with JWT, which use the same "secret"?

Tags: security, web, jwt, json-web-token

I try to create a Web application with JWT:

If a user send a request the server, I can run the process on the server and send the data back to the browser in a web token, that brings me to the question:

How can I verify this server response in the browser and send a new request to the server by using JWT with a secrete that can be accept from the server?

On the server the JWT from the browser request should be verify.

My consideration is to create a JWT on the client with the same "secret" but this is readable for attackers, because it is possible to read the source code (developer console).

Does there exist an way?

```
//Create request JWT
Request 1 --> {head: ...; data:..., secrete: secret}
//Request should be checkted on the server (secrete)  
// create a Resonse JWT and send back to the Client
Resonse 1 --> {head: ...; data:..., secrete: secret}
//Client verify the Respons JWT by the secrete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keep secret the private keys**. Sending them along the net is a dangerous solution because if they are stolen break the full system. You can use an assymetric RSA key pair instead of a symmetric. The JWT is signed with the private key and verified with the public

In the usual scenario, when user is not  identified, the server requires credentials to user in the browser, and issues a new JWT token. The client application in the browser include the JWT token in subsequent requests to authenticate. The server verifies token signature.

You propose that the browser also issue JWt tokens as a form of authentication. Consider the following:

- you will need an **assymetric key pair**
- **generate the keys in the browser**, do not send the private key by network
- **keep the key safe**: I suggest using the native webcryptography api, because unlike any other cryptographic library, allows to generate and use keys without exposing the content, ie can not be stolen
- **send the public key to server** and associate it with the user's account

Comment: Happy new year!! During the implementaion a question appear and I try to find a solution, but without success.I try to explane:
Step 1 - The user send a request (username and password), the request will be encrypted by the public key.
Step 2 - With the private key the server can decrypt and verify the user and send the resonse back. And here is the big unknown. How can I verify the resonse from the server on the browser ? I can only decrypt the code with the private key, but I have to keep this key private.

Comment: I know, that in case of using an assymetric key, it is necessary to run the following steps: 1 - client : token +public key to the server, 2. server: add the private key to the token and send it back to the client, 3. client: remove the public key and send the token with the private key to the server, then the decrytion can run success full. But currently I have no idea to realise it. I try to use the following APIs  https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt and https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign

Comment: comment 1) you need *two* key pairs, for client and server. Be aware that verify it is not the same as encrypt. Verification checks a digital signature on the content, and encryption hides the content of the message itself. An alternative is to use a symmetric encryption key shared by client and server. The client generates an AES key and send it to server, encrypted with the server RSA public key. Once the AES key is shared, all content is encrypted with this key in both directions. More or less is the same as the SSL / TLS protocol

Comment: comment 2) A token is encrypted with the public key and decrypted with the private (or with the AES key as commented above).  I do not know if those libraries support encryption or only signing/verifiyng. With a quick reading I have not seen it. If not, you can encrypt/decrypt yourself using native webcryptographyapi